# WPF listview, how to get sum of items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, collectionviewsource

I have the following listview defined(its items source is a collection of accounts with an AccountName and AccountBalance properties):

```
<ListView x:Name="AccountList1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedAccounts}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Background="LightGray">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="AccountName"   Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock>
                                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DataContext.Navigate}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountName}" />
                                </Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Balance" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AccountBalance}"/>
                </GridView>

            </ListView.View>
```

and this collection view to group the accounts by type:

```
  <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding AccountList}" x:Key="GroupedAccounts" >
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="AccountType" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

I want to display the sum of the accounts :
-The sum of all the accounts as the last item of the listview.
-The sum for each group of accounts.

Something like this:

BankAccounts

Account1  500$

Account2  150$

---

Total     650$

CashAccounts

Account3 0$

Account4 1000$

---

Total 1000$

---

AllTotal 1650$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a couple of ways to handle this situation.  You can either have your ViewModel handle the calculation and push it to your view or have a total property in your Model.  I don't know the pattern you're using, so I won't guess.  With that being said, there's a more reusable approach and that's to go with an aggregate converter, such as the one here:

```
public class SumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        Type valueType = value.GetType();

        if(valueType.Name == typeof(List<>).Name)
        {
            foreach (var item in (IList)value)
            {
                Type itemType = item.GetType();                     
                PropertyInfo itemPropertyInfo = itemType.GetProperty((string)parameter);
                double itemValue = (double)itemPropertyInfo.GetValue(item, null); 
                sum += itemValue;
            }
            return sum;
        }
        return 0.0;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    { throw new NotImplementedException();  }
}
```

This is based on this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28006/Using-converters-to-aggregate-a-list-in-a-ListView

It's not tested, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Got it working although I need to tweak how it's displayed a bit.